# Pyglet. OpenGL. How to draw rect in front of other based on "z" axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, 3d, pyglet

#### Envinronment:

Python: 3.6.6
pyglet version: 1.3.2
OS(reproduced on both): Windows 10 host, Ubuntu 14.04 guest (Virtualbox without 3d acceleration)

#### Code:

[code in github](https://github.com/Yuriy-Leonov/Pyglet_z_axis_issue)

```
import pyglet


class Window(pyglet.window.Window):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.position = [0, 0, 300.0]
        self.vertices_list = []

        # BLUE rect
        self.add_rect("blue.png", x=0, y=0, z=0)
        # RED rect
        self.add_rect("red.png", x=10, y=10, z=10)
        # Expects RED will be in front of BLUE, but it isn't
        # BLUE on top regardless of z value. I tried -10/10, etc.

        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.move_red_forward, 1 / 60)

    def add_rect(self, file_name, x, y, z):
        image = pyglet.image.load(file_name)
        image_grid = pyglet.image.ImageGrid(image, 1, 1)
        texture_grid = image_grid.get_texture_sequence()
        texture_group = pyglet.graphics.TextureGroup(texture_grid)
        x_ = (texture_group.texture.width + x)
        y_ = (texture_group.texture.height + y)
        tex_coords = ('t3f', texture_grid[0].texture.tex_coords)

        vert_list = self.batch.add(
            4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS,
            texture_group,
            ('v3f', (x, y, z,
                     x_, y, z,
                     x_, y_, z,
                     x, y_, z)),
            tex_coords)
        self.vertices_list.append(vert_list)

    def move_red_forward(self, dt):
        # move z += 1 for all corners
        red_vertices = self.vertices_list[1].vertices
        red_vertices[2] += 1
        red_vertices[5] += 1
        red_vertices[8] += 1
        red_vertices[11] += 1

    def set_3d(self):
        width, height = self.get_size()
        pyglet.graphics.glEnable(pyglet.graphics.GL_BLEND)
        pyglet.graphics.glBlendFunc(
            pyglet.graphics.GL_SRC_ALPHA,
            pyglet.graphics.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        pyglet.graphics.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        pyglet.graphics.glMatrixMode(pyglet.graphics.GL_PROJECTION)
        pyglet.graphics.glLoadIdentity()
        pyglet.graphics.gluPerspective(90, width / height, 0.1, 6000.0)
        pyglet.graphics.glMatrixMode(pyglet.graphics.GL_MODELVIEW)
        pyglet.graphics.glLoadIdentity()
        x, y, z = self.position
        pyglet.graphics.glTranslatef(x, y, -z)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.set_3d()
        self.batch.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window(width=1400, height=800, caption='Pyglet', resizable=True)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

#### Issue:

[image: part of screenshot]
The blue rect is drawn in front of the red. I expect that the `z` axis is responsible for defining which object should be drawn in front.

#### Question:

How I can achieve that?
Or did I miss something in the understanding of such process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test)

```
pyglet.graphics.glEnable(pyglet.graphics.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
```

Note, the default depth function is `GL_LESS`, this cause that a fragment is discarded, if a fragment has been drawn at the same place, and the new fragment has a depth which is greater or equal than the depth of the former fragment.

If the depth test is not enabled, then the later geometry is always drawn on top of the former.

---

If you want to blend the red image over the blue one, then the depth test has to be disabled and the red image has to be drawn after the blue image. For [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) the drawing order is crucial.The later object is blended to the former by the blending function ([`glBlendFunc`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml)) and blend equation ([`glBlendEquation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendEquation.xhtml)).
Change the order of the images:

```
 self.add_rect("red.png", x=10, y=10, z=10) 
 self.add_rect("blue.png", x=0, y=0, z=0)
```

Comment: But `GL_DEPTH_TEST` will break images with "alpha" layer :( Which value has effect for `z` axis same as "GL_DEPTH_TEST" and will keep "apla" transparency?

Comment: @YuriyLeonov In this case you have to respect the drawing order. The red image has to be drawn after the blue one.

Comment: I've change `glBlendFunc` on `glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0)` + added `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)` right after `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`. Only one issue left here: if any pixel in picture contains alpha more than 0 -> it will be drawn as non-transparent pixel. Pixels with `0` apha in RGBA is transparent. And I can't find way to calculate transparency as it was earlier :)

Comment: @YuriyLeonov Yes of course, the alpha test is not blending. The only way to mix fragments based on the alpha channel is blending. The alpha test can only  discard fragments completely, if the alpha test fails.